# How to add onclick listener to a element to get corresponding text

Tags: javascript, html

i have a list of pre tags

```
<pre class="fruit">mango</pre>
<pre class="fruit">apple</pre>
<pre class="fruit">guava</pre>
```

now i create  div tags dynamically and show next to pre tags .like this

[this is the jsfiddle preview with all the codes](https://jsfiddle.net/ocdqdgn7/)

---

[image]

---

now what i want is get text of `pre` when i click `div` next to it.for example if i click first green div i want to get `mango`.

but the problem is i can't understand how can i add listners to div to achive this.content of pre tags can be changed .

how i tried it

```
var box=box=document.getElementsByClassName("fruit");
for(var i=0;i<box.length;i++){
            var mydiv=document.createElement("div");
            mydiv.onclick= function(){func(i);};
}

function func(x){
    //alert(x); // x is always 4 because when this get fired i has increased to 4 in the loop.  
    var text = box[x].innerText || box[x].textContent;
    alert(text);
}
```

the problem is when `funt()` trigger value of i has changed .how can i achieve this ??

Comment: @jamiec and everyone thanks you so much ..now it's working ..i searched lot but it's hard to search because no idea what is the keywords to seach

Comment: I am guessing you have the answer but try this anyway, https://jsfiddle.net/ocdqdgn7/1/, the solution is the best but the one with least changes to your code.

Comment: @whiletrue I could try and help you to fix this code but here is better approach https://jsfiddle.net/ocdqdgn7/2/